# Which type of amplifier has feedback? BJT, FET or both

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, bjt, power-electronics, fet

[image]
The answer to this question is given in the picture shared but I am not able to understand the answer or rather I would prefer to say I do not agree to the answer given. So I need to know what will be the right answer.

Comment: They are both transistors, not amplifiers. You can use them to build amplifiers with various kinds of feedback

Comment: I feel something is missing. Isn't there an actual _circuit_ here?

Comment: Cit: *...No parts of this book may be reproduced...* Of course  they must be ashame of such question and  try not to pass it around!

Comment: @PlasmaHH agree... That's what is my point. But as they have mentioned hre will be providing feedback which I am not able to get. How is it even possible?

Comment: You could speculate that they're talking about the emitter resistance in a BJT providing negative feedback in a common emitter amplifier configuration, but as written, without additional details or schematics the question and answer border on absurd.

Comment: If they count hre as "feedback" in a BJT then surely the (often rather large) Miller capacitance in a FET also counts...

Comment: If you have to study the book, then study the book. But when you are done with this class, burn the book and get a real one somewhere and somehow.

Comment: Both mosfet and bjt have feedback when configured as a follower. But not in other configurations. Which is why this is such a terrible question.

Comment: Fig x shows a BJT amplifier and a FET amplifier, with reference to these two amplifiers answer the following 39 questions ...

Comment: @Chu, OK. If that is the case then I retract my sentiment.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not well worded, but the answer makes it clear.

Transistors can be modeled using h-parameters. One of these is the so called "voltage feedback ratio" \$h_{re}\$ which is defined as
$$
 h_{re} = \frac{V_{be}}{V_{ce}}, \quad I_b =0
$$
It basically describes the feeback from the output voltage to the input voltage of the transistor. Due to the early effect a change of \$V_{ce}\$ changes the collector current which in turn alters the base-emitter voltage. So the output voltage is fed back to the input of the transistor.

For a FET, lacking an equivalent to the base current, this kind of feedback is not there and therefore the BJT has feedback from the output to input while the FET doesn't.

Out of context this question is difficult to understand, but maybe after the corresponding section in the textbook the answer is more obvious. Could be a good book after all (or not).